# Version numbering of Debian package for local custom packages

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I would like to build and package a particular Go program. The packaged versions of said program provided by Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 9.5 (actually PVE 5.2) are all fairly old, compared to what I could get from upstream.

Getting the dependencies for my build right isn't an issue, neither is building a Debian package (been there, done that).

What I need to know is how I can assign a version to my package - which isn't going  be released to anyone else - such that *should* the package maintainer ever release a newer version than my package has, it would get installed and replace my own package (one such situation could be Ubuntu's `do-release-upgrade`).

Is there some way to "tag" a package in such a way without breaking the internal version comparisons (`dpkg --compare-versions`)?

I know the backports typically have `bpo` in the package name (or is that the version?), but it would be hard to find a comprehensive list of all similar "tags" and so I was thinking perhaps there is already a method to achieve this and avoid clashes. So the main goal is to play by the rules, all the while getting the newest version I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re packaging new upstream versions, I would recommend a version of the form

```
1.0-0~c0000022l+1
```

where 1.0 is the upstream version. The idea here is as follows:

- 0 is lower than any official Debian package will ever have; this is used for example in Ubuntu packages which ship a newer upstream version than Debian (you’ll see `0ubuntu` here);
- ~ ensures that the version will sort lower than any -0 revision anyway (see [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#version) for details);
- c0000022l is some specific suffix to tag the revision as yours (similar to `bpo` for backports, `deb` for Debian stable updates...);
- +1 gives you room for future updates to your packaging.

If you then need to provide a newer package with only packaging fixes, you’d bump the +1. If you package a newer upstream version, you bump the upstream version as appropriate and start from +1 again.

If the same upstream, or a newer one, ever ends up packaged “officially”, it will be a valid upgrade candidate from your local version: if it’s a Ubuntu package, 1.0-0ubuntu... will sort after 1.0-0~, and if it’s a Debian package, 1.0-1 will sort after 1.0-0.