# Silencing apt conflicts when package is newer than other packages require

Tags: apt

I have a custom variant of some package that provides keyboard layouts. I did not want `apt-get` to overwrite it with any new variant so I created version 3.0.0, the current repository version is 2.12.3. It has broken `apt-get upgrade` as some system packages Depends on <=2.12.3. I am sure it is working with my 3.0.0 version but can not install anything. A temporary solution was to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and remove the dependency.

Is there some other way to pretend that my package 3.0.0 actually satisfy <=2.12.3 by means of equivs or forcing apt to ignore this issue?

According to comments, the proper solution would be to make 2.12.3~hold and mark it with `apt-mark hold`. However this solution does not apply when e.g. I install something from upstream and would like to force other packages think that it actually satisfies  Depends<=2.12.3. Is there a way to silence package managers without having to play with the package versioning? Rather than marking a package not to be overwritten, I would welcome marking the package for its dependencies not to be tested.

Comment: `# apt-mark hold <your-package>`

Comment: I may be missing something, but the normal way to stop a package being changed is to "hold" or "pin" it.

Comment: The easiest fix would be to build your package again, this time with a version like `2.12.3-0~local`, install it, and then `apt-mark hold` it.   BTW, questions similar to this have been answered before on U&L, e.g. see [Version numbering of Debian package for local custom packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479884/version-numbering-of-debian-package-for-local-custom-packages).  PS: RE "dependency hell in Debian", there is no hell that you do not make for yourself.

Comment: `apt-mark hold` answers my question if I update the version. I was not aware of it. There is a variant of the question when I install something from unstable and would like to force ignore any < Depends.

Comment: Don't install packages from unstable onto a stable system.  and especially don't try to get it to ignore versioned dependencies (if a package has a versioned dependency then you can be sure that it's versioned for good reason!).   Instead, check https://backports.debian.org/ to see if the package(s) you want have been backported.  If not, either stick with the version in stable or backport it yourself.   Finally, it looks like you need to read [Don't Break Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)

Answer (score 4):

The solution is not to artificially inflate the version of your package. Mark it as conflicting with and obsoleting the original package, and keep the proper versioning.

Comment: The problem is that Depends requirements are usually just a wishes of developers and it does not mean that older or newer dependency would break the package. So it is reasonable to ask for more user control about depends. I really see no reason why `xserver-xorg` shall be implicitly dependent on the version of the package, which provides statically generated keyboard layouts, which are the same for last twenty years!

Comment: @VojtaK if they really were the same for the last twenty years, then the devs are probably even more justified in a strong version dependency, as who knows what sort of breakage any sort of actual change might bring.

Comment: @VojtaK I would not assume that. Quite the contrary is the case. If someone specified a maximum version in dependencies in their debian package, they probably had a good reason

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the new package has the same name as the distro package, so there’s nothing to conflict with.

Comment: @StephenKitt ah, that would be something to fix first